# node sqlite3 Database#get callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sqlite

I am trying to check whether database has this item, if there is an item do not add to database, if not insert into database. 
And I get to a loop through a for-loop and run db.get on a select statement, and on callback run another statement.

```
db.serialize(function (){
  var stmt1 = db.prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL, ?)");

  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
    db.get("SELECT * FROM table where col_name like '" + myarray[i].name + "'",[], function(err, row){
      if(typeof row == "undefined"){ //empty result set
        console.log(i);
        stmt1.run( myarray[i].name );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Problem: when I log index i, i have i = 10, and myarray only have myarray[9] length.